# Render a grid of items directly in Ionic 2/ Angular 2 template

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a list of items that I'd like to render in 3 col * x rows grid. I'm not sure how to do that in the Angular 2 or Ionic 2. Being reading through https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html# for a while now, here is what I did:

```
<ion-grid>
 <ion-row *ngIf="i%3 == 0" #i>
  <ion-col width-33 *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" >
    <ion-card>
     <img src="{{item.image}}" />
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>
          {{item.title}}
        </ion-card-title>
        <p></p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
   </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

which doesn't work. As a work around, I can break my list of items into chunks before they are passed to the template, but I suppose it's a bit more elegant let the template handling it - if it can.

What are the correct directives and syntaxes to use?

Answer (score 6):

I know this an old post, however i worked out a way to have this work using ionic/angular.

Placing wrap in the row, then giving each column a width of 4 base units (col-4)
will give the desired effect and its all declarative.

NOTE: There is a default of 12 columns in the grid.
col-6 gives 2 columns, col-3 gives 4 columns etc.

```
 <ion-row wrap>
    <ion-col col-4  *ngFor="let image of imageList" (tap)="setAvatar(image)">
      <img [src]="image">
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <div style="  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: stretch;">
    <div *ngFor="#s of items; let i = index" style="flex: 0 0 calc( 100% / 3 - 2px );">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" padding>{{i}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

use flex box...

see plunker here

http://plnkr.co/edit/8lbKDG?p=info